# Is there a way for me to take user input from an interest calculator that I made in JavaScript and add that automatically into my chartjs dataset?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to get my user input from my javascript interest calculator to go directly into the dataset of my chartjs so that the graph will automatically change and reanimate with the new data. Is there a way for me to do so? Below I have the code that I am currently using for the chart (which is a line chart). Any feedback would be great thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Graph</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script>
            let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

            let lineChart = new Chart(myChart, {                
                type: 'line',
                data:{
                    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
                    datasets: [{ 
                        label: "Population",
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor:[ "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)"],
                        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        boarderCapStyle: 'butt',
                        boarderDash: [],
                        boarderDashOffset: 0.0,
                        pointBoarderColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                        pointBoarderWidth: 1,
                        pointHoverRadius: 5,
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
                        pointHoverBoarderColor: "rgba(220, 220, 220, 1)",
                        pointHoverBoarderWidth: 2,
                        pointRadius: 1,
                        pointHitRadius: 10,
                        data:[
                        65,
                        59,
                        80,
                        81,
                        56,
                        55,
                        40
                        ]
                    }]
        },
        options:{
            scales:{
                yAxes:[{
                    ticks:{
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the code for your interest calculator?  Is it on a separate page from your chart?

Comment: The code for the calculator would be on the same page. I do have the code for the interest calculator but it is too long for the comment bar.

Comment: If it is on the same page then I would edit your question and add it to your existing code.